# Diffie-Hellman secret key choices

Tags: diffie-hellman, keys

I'm trying to understand why the secret keys used by Alice and Bob in Diffie-Hellman are $a,b ∈ ℤ∗p$.

Say $a$ is $p - 1$, wouldn't the transmitted $g^a$ be 1 mod $p$ by $FLT$? Now anytime a passive listener sees a 1 being transmitted would know one of the secret keys and could easily compute the message. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "obvious" (it really isn't *that* obvious) thing you are missing is: **The same reasoning could be applied to literally *any* other private key!** There is nothing special about $a=\lvert(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times\rvert=p-1$ (which would, by the way, more commonly be represented as $0$ modulo itself), except that checking for it is particularly easy. For instance, if an attacker suspects that your private key is $42$, they can simply compute $g^{42}\bmod p$ and compare it to the public key $g^a\bmod p$ you transmitted. Does this imply that $42$ is a weak private key?

The reason why Diffie-Hellman (and in fact, similar fallacies apply to any cryptosystem) can still be secure is that **the probability of each single key occurring is negligible**. An attacker *can* test whether your private key equals something, but it takes a certain amount of time (a bit less for $a=0$, but still). When the set of possible keys is reasonably large, the attacker can't search through a meaningful subset of in their lifetime, hence they will, with overwhelming probability, not be able to guess the correct private key.

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing special about most key values, the public key 1 is actually not permitted. It would result in the same shared secret 1 with every other key, because $1^x = 1$ for any private key $x$. When using [public key validation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2631#section-2.1.5), the key is checked to be in the range $[2, p-1]$. This is ensured if the private key [is chosen](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2631#section-2.2) from $[2, q-2]$.

For other "special" values, like 42, the logic from @yyyyyyy's answer applies.